# Drop-down list filtering

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a drop-down list called application and another drop-down list called navigation.  All of the navigation items has a corresponding application id that can be filtered based on the application chosen in the first drop-down list.

How can I pass the application ID from the application drop-down list to the navigation component?

I tried using @Input('value') appId: number; in navigation.component.ts to get the app.Id from the application component, but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

app.component.html

```
<app-application></app-application>
<br/>
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
```

application.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="applications">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let app of apps" [value]="app.Id">
      {{app.ApplicationName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

application.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationService } from '../application.service';
import { IApplication } from '../IApplication';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application',
  templateUrl: './application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  apps: Array<IApplication>;

  constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService) { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.applicationService
      .getApplications()
      .subscribe(data => {this.apps = data; } );
  }
}
```

navigation.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="navigations">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let nav of navigations" [value]="nav.Id">
    {{nav.NavName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

navigation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../navigation.service';
import { INavigation } from '../INavigation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  appId = 1;
  //@Input('value') appId: number;
  navigations: Array<INavigation>;

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.navigationService
      .getNavigations(this.appId)
      .subscribe(data => {this.navigations = data; });
      console.log(this.appId);
  }

}
```

Comment: Use a service to share data, input/ouputs work only in child/parent relationship.

Comment: Can you give an example on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service which you can use to pass on the data whenever it changes in the `app-application` component. You can use a `Subject` for this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class ShareAppIdService {

  constructor() { }

  private appId = new Subject();  // private subject

  public changeAppId(value) {   // use this method in the app-application to send the appId to app-navigation
    this.appId.next(value);
  }

  public appIdChanged = this.appId.asObservable();  // subscribe this in app-navigation to get the changed data
}
```

In the application component, attach a click listener to the options

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="applications">
      <mat-option (click)="sendChangedId(app.Id)" *ngFor="let app of apps" [value]="app.Id">
        {{app.ApplicationName}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the ts file of the application component, Inject the `ShareAppIdService` service and have a method like:

```
sendChangedId(appId) {
    this.sharedAppIdService.changeAppId(appId);
}
```

In your app-navigation ts, inject the shared service and subscribe to `appIdChanged`.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sharedAppIdService.appIdChanged.subscribe((appId) => {
        this.navigationService
            .getNavigations(appId).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.navigations = data;
            });
    })
}
```

Comment: From navigation.component.html, I want to pass the "nav" to a component that shows the details of the nav item chosen.  Do I use the outputEmitter for that?

Comment: Please read what are input/output properties. How and when to use them. In your case, if your navigation component and navigation detail component are not related by a child-parent relationship then you have to use services itself! Also please give a though about the architecture of the app, you may want to make these components as related components.